# XUbuntu 17.04 - Install KDE without breaking Xfce config files

Tags: xubuntu, kubuntu, kde

How to install KDE Plasma and all required widget but without installing the whole KDE desktop environment?

I tried installing `kubuntu-desktop` but it broke my Xfce config (e.g. all icons in Xfce got replaced with icons from KDE). I use XUbuntu 17.04.

Answer (score 0):

Don't quote me yet (I'm still working through this myself, but I have done this in the past as well -- and it worked). Simply reinstall ubuntustudio-desktop after you finish with your kubuntu-desktop (or plasma-desktop) install. I had to redo some things I had customized (like panels) but I didn't backup my xfce configuration first (which you can do if you go into your panel preferences -- though it is a bit janky). I'm currently working through the hybrid installs with 18.04.